# Tableau Dynamic Map Labelling

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

The map I'm making has the labels for markers overlapping unless I zoom in so much that only a small section of the map is visible. I'm presenting the map as one static picture of the entire state that is supposed to show all of the marker labels. Is there a way I can display a view of the map that will show the entire state I'm trying to display in one image with all of the marker labels visible? [Here is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v55SK.jpg)